# Access the scene from anywhere

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a cocos2d hierarchy of layers that is very very deep.  I want to access my scene from any of the layers?  How would I do this?

If I use a singleton will the retain on the singleton prevent the layer from being garbage collected when scenes are changed using the director?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess one approch is to use [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene sould do the trick if you want to get access to the current running scene, but about decleraing your scene as a singleton yes it prevents garbage collector if you retain your scene whenever iit's created but you have to remeber to release it whenever you are done with your scene.